# how to use strtol to parse random number of ints in a string?

Tags: c, while-loop, c-strings, strtol

I have a program that reads input with fgets:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[128];
    fgets(buf, 128, stdin);
}
```

I would like the user to enter any amount of integers. However i am not sure how to parse them.
I did some research and found strtol(). So my question is how can i use strtol to parse ints and print them? here is what i tried:

```
int main() {

    char buf[128];

    char *a = buf;
    char *b;
    fgets(buf, 128, stdin);

    while (1) {

          long x = strtol(a, &b, 10);
          printf("%ld ", x);
          a = b;

          if (b == buf+strlen(buf))
              break;
    }
```

Comment: Use `strtok()` to find the tokens, then call `strtol()` on each token.

Comment: Barmar's right that `strtok` is the more usual approach, but you ought to be able to do it with `strtol` alone. The code you posted looks mostly okay.   What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @SteveSummit it does not break out of the loop, the input i provided is "1 2 3 4 5"

Comment: The problem is you're not checking for `strtol` failure.  After calling `strtol`, if it's the case that `b` is equal to `a`, this means that `strtol` found nothing to convert, and it's another indication that you're done.  This happens, for example, when you get to the `\n` at the end of the line, that `fgets` left there.

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that according to the description of the function in the C Standard

> 7 If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form,
> no conversion is performed; **the value of nptr is stored in the object
> pointed to by endptr**, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.

You can write something like shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";

    const char *p = s;
    while ( 1 )
    {
        char *next;

        long int x = strtol( p, &next, 10 );

        if (next != p)
        {
            printf( "%ld ", x );
            p = next;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```